# MVC Partial View Takes me to a new page instead of keeping me on the main page

Tags: c#

```
When I select an employee from the dropdownlist instead of keeping me on the main page it takes me to a new blank page for the partial view. I want the partial view to remain on the main page. My _Layout page also has these jquery files.

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

**This is the code for My Dashboard controller**

```
       public ActionResult ManagerAssignedTask(ManagerAssignedTasksFilterViewModel assignedTasksFilterViewModel, GridSortOptions gridSortOptions, int page = 1)
        {
            gridSortOptions.Column = (gridSortOptions.Column == "undefined") ? null : gridSortOptions.Column;

            var employeeTasks = this._serviceSession.EmployeeTaskRepository.FilterEmployeeTasks(assignedTasksFilterViewModel.EmployeeId)
                .OrderBy(gridSortOptions.Column ?? "CaseId", gridSortOptions.Direction)
                .AsPagination(page, PageSize);

            this.ViewBag.FundingConsultants = EmployeeHelper.FindFundingConsultants(this._masterDataSession, new RoleProvider());

            foreach (var task in employeeTasks)
            {
                task.AssignedBy = task.AssignedBy ?? "UNKNOWN";
                task.Description = task.Description.Truncate(70);
                task.EndUser= task.EndUser ?? "UNKNOWN";
            }

            this.ViewBag.Header = "Assigned Task";
            return PartialView("_ManagerAssignedTaskList", new GridViewModel<EmployeeTask> { Items = employeeTasks, GridSortOptions = gridSortOptions });
        }
```

**_ManagerAssignedTasksList**
        This is the code for the view

```
    @using System.Web.Optimization
    @using MvcContrib
    @using OMI.Web.Extensions
    @model OMI.Web.ViewModels.GridViewModel<OMI.Data.Model.EmployeeTask>

    <h3>@ViewBag.Header</h3>
    @Html.Partial("_ManagerAssignedTasksFilterBox", new OMI.Web.ViewModels.Dashboard.ManagerAssignedTasksFilterViewModel())
    @Html.Grid(Model.Items, 1).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions).RowAttributes(row => new Hash(@class => row.Item.DateDue < DateTime.Now ? "assignTaskRowColor" : "")).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.For(c => Html.ActionLink(c.CaseId.ToString(), "Details", "Case", new { id = c.CaseId }, null)).Named("Case Id").SortColumnName("CaseId");
        columns.For(c => c.EndUser).Named("End User").SortColumnName("EndUser");
        columns.For(c => c.StateProvince).Named("State").SortColumnName("StateProvince");
        columns.For(c => Html.ActionLink(c.EmployeeTaskId.ToString(), "Details", "EmployeeTask", new { employeeTaskId = c.EmployeeTaskId }, null)).Named("Task Id").SortColumnName("EmployeeTaskId");
        columns.For(c => c.AssignedBy).Named("Assigned By").SortColumnName("AssignedBy");
        columns.For(c => c.DateDue).Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}").Named("Due Date").SortColumnName("DateDue");
        columns.For(c => c.Description).Named("Description").SortColumnName("Description");
        columns.For(c => @Html.Raw("<a title='Done' class='btn btn-mini btn-success' href='#' onclick = 'markTaskAsComplete(" + c.EmployeeId + "," + c.EmployeeTaskId) + "," + c.CaseId + ")'><i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i></a> ").Encode(false).SortColumnName("").Visible(false);
    })
    @Html.Raw(Html.Pager(Model.Items).ToString())
```

**This is my partial view code-_ManagerAssignedTasksFilterBox**

```
@using OMI.Web.Extensions
@model OMI.Web.ViewModels.Dashboard.ManagerAssignedTasksFilterViewModel

<div class="well">
    <h3>SEARCH EMPLOYEE</h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ManagerAssignedTask", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-inline", id = "employeeDropDown", target="_self"}))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeId, new SelectList(ViewBag.FundingConsultants,"Value","Text"), new { onchange = "$('#employeeDropDown').submit()" })
    }
</div>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Yes, you're calling `.submit()` in the onchange handler for the dropdown.  That will cause a form submit which loads a new page.

Comment: I want to be able to filter the grid based on what I select from the dropdown so I would need the .submit() method.

Comment: Still need a solution to my problem.

Comment: Well, it's not what you're doing.  Form posts, particularly those with Get methods, cause the page to reload when submitted.  It sounds like you need to develop an Ajax method, but that is far beyond the scope of a simple answer here.

Comment: Do you mean using Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm?

Comment: I'm unclear on what it is that you are trying to accomplish.  Your post indicates you want ajaxy behavior, but you have not written anything ajaxy.  Do you want an Ajax filtering, or do you want the page to reload with the filtered data?

Comment: Also, don't use target="_self".  Target has been deprecated for a very long time.